# Give title frame different background than other frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, pgfornament

I am trying to style my `title frame` differently than the rest of my frames using `beamer`.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\title{The Patience Study}
\author[TeX User]{TeX User}
\institute{University of Kyoto}

\tikzset{
    position in page centre/.style={
        shift={(current page.south)}
    },
}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}

%%%Titlepage
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,position in page centre]
\node[] at (-5.5,8.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{39}};
\node[] at (5.5,8.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{40}};
%
\node[] at (-5.5,0.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm, symmetry=h]{39}};
\node[] at (5.5,0.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm, symmetry=h]{40}};
%

\end{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \vfill
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.1em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%
      \vskip-0.4em\par
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfornament[width=1cm]{75};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \vskip0.5em\par
      \usebeamerfont{author}\small\insertauthor\par
      \vskip1.2em%
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
      \vskip0.1em%
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \vskip0.1em%
    {\scriptsize{\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate}}
    \vfill
}
\makeatother

%%%Background
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,position in page centre]
\foreach \i in {-4,...,4}
\node[] at (\i,0.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{70}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\framesubtitle{Basic Research Question}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The normal frames appear like so with the decorative figure at the base, as expected:

[image: Normal_Frame]

However, the title frame also has the decorative figure at its base as well which is undesirable:

[image: Title_Frame]

How do I make designs for the frame background independently from the title frame? Is there something like `\setbeamertemplate{normal frame}`?

I did look in the `beamer` manual, but couldn't find help there (or may have missed it).

I also consulted with a previous solution posted about 11 years ago here: [Different backgrounds for title and "normal" frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31316/different-backgrounds-for-title-and-normal-frames-in-beamer), but it does not seem to translate well to my problem. The `pgfornaments` do not appear on the frame at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same technique as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1004#a1198

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\title{The Patience Study}
\author[TeX User]{TeX User}
\institute{University of Kyoto}

\tikzset{
    position in page centre/.style={
        shift={(current page.south)}
    },
}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}

%%%Titlepage
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,position in page centre]
\node[] at (-5.5,8.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{39}};
\node[] at (5.5,8.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{40}};
%
\node[] at (-5.5,0.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm, symmetry=h]{39}};
\node[] at (5.5,0.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm, symmetry=h]{40}};
%

\end{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \vfill
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.1em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%
      \vskip-0.4em\par
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfornament[width=1cm]{75};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \vskip0.5em\par
      \usebeamerfont{author}\small\insertauthor\par
      \vskip1.2em%
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
      \vskip0.1em%
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \vskip0.1em%
    {\scriptsize{\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate}}
    \vfill
}

\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{}
    \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}

\makeatother

%%%Background
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,position in page centre]
\foreach \i in {-4,...,4}
\node[] at (\i,0.75) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{70}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\framesubtitle{Basic Research Question}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, once again!

Comment: @Ginko-Mitten You're welcome!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323638/94293

Comment: @user94293 Oh, thanks for finding this! I added it as duplicate target to the question.